# Plot one dimensional categorical variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a single categorical variable, in sequence, using only color to differentiate the points. Eg. `factor(mtcars$cyl)` being plotted as a line or "tile" map with each data point (slice or square of the line or rectangular map area) represented by a color corresponding to the `cyl` value.

What would such a plot type be called? What `geom` would be used for this?

**EDIT:** Not the prettiest, but this works: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=seq_len(nrow(mtcars)), y = "")) + geom_tile(aes(fill = factor(cyl)))`

Also, multiple such plots faceted together:

`ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=seq_len(nrow(mtcars)), y = factor(am))) + geom_tile(aes(fill = factor(cyl))) + facet_grid(am ~ ., scales = "free")`

[image]

Please let me know of any more elegant methods.

Comment: Are you looking for a heatmap?

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian Hmm perhaps. This incomplete code is almost what I want: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=seq_len(nrow(mtcars)), y = ???)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = cyl))` but what do I put for `y` if I just want the one dimension?

Comment: Ok, the dimensions aren't the prettiest, but this works: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=seq_len(nrow(mtcars)), y = "")) + geom_tile(aes(fill = factor(cyl)))`. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: There's `geom_rug`, though that's usually added on to a two-dimensional plot.

Comment: @alistaire I don't know if `geom_rug` can be used without the main plot. More importantly I think that's a flattened histogram for visualizing frequency of data. I prefer even spacing.